# How to use VB6 DLL (Active X/COM) in Python?

Tags: python, com, vb6, activex

I created a VB6 DLL and it is registered on my PC. I have pywin32 and python2.7 installed. I ran makepy in the win32com\client dir and chose the appropriate DLL. I am now at a loss as to how to use this DLL in my Python program...examples on the Web show win32com.client.Dispatch(X), but what do I use for X? How do I use a human readable name to access this DLL in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter that should be in Dispatch is a string called the ProgID (Program ID). This is of the form `<projectname>.<classname>` . So for instance, if your VB6 project was called BusinessLib, and it contained a Public class called Formulae, the string would be `BusinessLib.Formulae`.

Comment: Actually, what is the makepy generated file used for?